# Firestore: how to specify the firestore key to be used for merge?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function written in nodejs and another in python. They both do the same thing in different scripts.

I currently have a function that creates a firestore collection called `profile`, then insert a document, which has as a name, the document id created by firestore

The document itself contains an object, representing the user, first name, last name, email, and phone.

the phone is a list, or array `[]`, it always contains just one phone number, later on we'll add multiple phone numbers per user but for now, you can assume that there is just one element in a list. Phone can never be null, email can be null sometimes.

What I want to do, is if the phone doesn't exist already then insert a new user, otherwise update the existing user. So there should be no duplication.

Can this be done via `merge` in firestore or `update` or should I do a `where` query? I know that a query is always possible, but I want to know if I can use a `merge` on a list field in firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any document reference to update to and need to query the field `phone_number` then you need to use the `where()` method with the `array_contains` operator. Use the `array_contains` operator to filter based on array values. If a document is found you can use `arrayUnion()` to add elements to an array but only elements are not already present. See sample snippets below:

**Python:**

```
# Collection Reference
col_ref = db.collection(u'profile')
# Check collection if there's any array in documents that contains the `phone_number`
admin_ref = col_ref.where(u'phone_number', u'array_contains', 12345).get()

# Checks if there's a result.
if admin_ref:
  # Iterate the result 
  for item in admin_ref:
    doc = col_ref.document(item.id)
    doc.update(
      # Adds multiple phone numbers to the field, but only adds new ones.
      {u'phone_number': firestore.ArrayUnion([12345,54321])})
# If there's no result, then add a document with the field name `phone_number`
else:
  col_ref.add({'phone_number': [123456]})
```

---

For more information, you can check these documentations:

- [Array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)
- [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)